# Shiny app to rmd: Emergency stop in LaTeX failed to compile, .tex not empty

Tags: r, shiny, latex, r-markdown, knitr

#### Issue (reprex at bottom):

- Want to download dynamic reports from shiny app to rmd then knit pdf
- `options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE)` gives me:

```
"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/quarto/bin/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS report.knit.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output pandoc4788153d65c7.tex --lua-filter "C:\Users\Toadstool\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:\Users\Toadstool\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\latex-div.lua" --self-contained --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --variable "geometry:margin=1in" 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
```

- the eventual error on download attempt is:

```
Warning: Error in : LaTeX failed to compile C:\Users\TOADST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpspbOXs\file4788643e23c9.tex. 
See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips.
  [No stack trace available]
```

- That file.tex has contents in it and is readable by notepad+. I can see that the contents are what is intended, it has the correct names of the params and expected outputs. So the params are being successfully passed on to the rmd
- knitting the rmd directly successfully gives me a pdf
- I verified by running this successfully:

```
writeLines(c(
  '\\documentclass{article}',
  '\\begin{document}', 'Hello world!', '\\end{document}'
), 'test.tex')
tinytex::pdflatex('test.tex')
```

- If I were to change the shiny app and rmd to html it will work (can also be done in reprex)
- the .log file in that folder seen in the warning message is where I see the emergency stop message, and I'm not sure how to get around this:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.6.24)  24 JUN 2022 08:43
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**C:/Users/TOADST~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpspbOXs/file4788c2a49f4.tex
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
<*> C:/Users/TOADST~
                    1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpspbOXs/file4788c2a49f4.tex 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 4 strings out of 479997
 111 string characters out of 5886450
 292771 words of memory out of 5000000
 18292 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 469259 words of font info for 28 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 3i,0n,0p,1b,6s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

#### What I tried:

- going to that url in the error message, most similar errors had to do with MikTex, which I had previously installed. I [removed MikTex through cmd](https://miktex.org/faq/uninstall-miktex-win-cli)
- running `Sys.which('pdflatex')` returns `"C:\\Users\\MyUsername\\AppData\\Roaming\\TinyTeX\\bin\\win32\\pdflatex.exe"` confirming R is using TinyTeX
- I followed the debugging on Yihui's page. I installed tinytex through `remotes::install_github('rstudio/tinytex')`  and also tried `tinytex::install_tinytex(version = "latest")`
- As suggested by Yihui as I ran this as well as other suggestions Yuhui gave in the comments

```
update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)
tinytex::tlmgr_update()
```

- information about the emergency stop message leads me to `\end{document}` but I don't know how to incorporate this in my shiny-rmd scenario. [See here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354518/what-does-the-emergency-stop-error-mean)

#### Reprex:

##### Shiny:

```r
# reprex app
library(shiny)
library(tibble)

df <- tribble(
             ~name,  ~pheno,   ~geno,
  "Luke Skywalker", "blond", "light",
     "Darth Vader",  "none",  "dark"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton("reportbut", "Download your report")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$reportbut <- downloadHandler(
    # For html output, change this to "report.html"
    filename = "report.pdf",

    content = function(file){
      # Copy the report file to a temporary directory before processing it, in
      # case we don't have write permissions to the current working dir (which
      # can happen when deployed)
      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
      file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)

      # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
      params <- list(name = df$name, df = df, pheno = df$pheno, geno = df$geno)

      # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
      # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
      # from the code in this app)
      rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                        params = params,
                        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()))
    }
  )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8071
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)
#>  os       Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32
#>  ui       RTerm
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  English_United States.utf8
#>  ctype    English_United States.utf8
#>  tz       America/New_York
#>  date     2022-06-24
#>  pandoc   2.17.1.1 @ C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/quarto/bin/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version date (UTC) lib source
#>  bslib         0.3.1   2021-10-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  cachem        1.0.6   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  callr         3.7.0   2021-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  cli           3.3.0   2022-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  crayon        1.5.1   2022-03-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  curl          4.3.2   2021-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  digest        0.6.29  2021-12-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  ellipsis      0.3.2   2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  evaluate      0.15    2022-02-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  fansi         1.0.3   2022-03-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  fastmap       1.1.0   2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  fontawesome   0.2.2   2021-07-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  fs            1.5.2   2021-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  glue          1.6.2   2022-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  highr         0.9     2021-04-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  htmltools     0.5.2   2021-08-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  httpuv        1.6.5   2022-01-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  httr          1.4.3   2022-05-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  jquerylib     0.1.4   2021-04-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  jsonlite      1.8.0   2022-02-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  knitr         1.39    2022-04-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  later         1.3.0   2021-08-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  lifecycle     1.0.1   2021-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  magrittr      2.0.3   2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  mime          0.12    2021-09-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  pillar        1.7.0   2022-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  pkgconfig     2.0.3   2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  processx      3.6.1   2022-06-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  promises      1.2.0.1 2021-02-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  ps            1.7.1   2022-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  R6            2.5.1   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  Rcpp          1.0.8.3 2022-03-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  reprex        2.0.1   2021-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  rlang         1.0.2   2022-03-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  rmarkdown     2.14    2022-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  rstudioapi    0.13    2020-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  sass          0.4.1   2022-03-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  shiny       * 1.7.1   2021-10-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  stringi       1.7.6   2021-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  stringr       1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  tibble      * 3.1.7   2022-05-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  utf8          1.2.2   2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  vctrs         0.4.1   2022-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  webshot       0.5.3   2022-04-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  withr         2.5.0   2022-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  xfun          0.31    2022-05-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  xml2          1.3.3   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  xtable        1.8-4   2019-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  yaml          2.3.5   2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#> 
#>  [1] C:/Users/Toadstool/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2
#>  [2] C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.0/library
#> 
#> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

##### Rmd

````
---
title: "SO You're My Only Hope"
author: "SWtP"
date: '2022-06-23'
output: pdf_document
params: 
  name: NA
  df: NA
  pheno: NA
  geno: NA
---

```{r, include=FALSE}
options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE)
```

```{r echo=FALSE}
# The `params` object is available in the document.
params$name
params$df
params$pheno
params$geno
```
````

Comment: can you TLDR your steps in a high-level manner? is your main problem a `tex -> pdf` conversion ?

Comment: shiny app to rmd good, rmd to tex good, tex to pdf bad.

Comment: It works on my system (Linux based). From the error it seems the tilde (~) within the path is the issue. Try using another path as temp dir.

Comment: Yeah it works on my Mac as well. I suspect it's definitely Windows then. I tried to [disable](https://www.tecklyfe.com/windows-server-tip-disable-8-3-naming-strip-existing-short-names/) the 8dot3 naming convention, but R is still recognizing ~1. I'll try changing my temp dir to a shorter username. Changing `rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file` to `output_file = "PATH/filename.pdf"` works, but defeats the purpose of circumventing potential deployment issues.